where I update the magento2 to the 2.4.6-p5 the page is show empty where I click the url
The browers open a blank page when I click a url,but it work where I refresh the page!
can somebody tell me what happen?
My website work well on 2.4.3 the issue appear when I update it to the 2.4.6-p5

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Try to change ttl attribute value or comment ttl code and check may it will work.

@cc
Hey,
Navigate to:
/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template/File/Validator.php:113

replace code in function  "isPathInDirectories"

protected function isPathInDirectories($path, $directories)
{
    $realPath = str_replace('', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));
    if (!is_array($directories)) {
        $directories = (array)$directories;
    }
    foreach ($directories as $directory) {
        if (0 === strpos($realPath, $directory)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

Thank You!
